# Facebook messenger returning error on valid message request

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, php-7.1

currently all bots developed by me (including several production bots which have been in use for a while) stopped replying to messages. According to logs, Messenger is returning the following response:

```
(
  [error] => Array
    (
        [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
        [type] => OAuthException
        [code] => 2500
        [fbtrace_id] => C9ExJBwjvfp
    )

)
```

This is deeply frusturating, because the bots have been working well and the issue appeared in deployed bots which have been working independently for a while.

The request is as follows:

```
(
    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1783672501695199
        )

    [message] => Array
        (
            [text] => MESSAGE_TEXT
        )

    [tag] => 
    [notification_type] => REGULAR
    [messaging_type] => RESPONSE
    [access_token] => XXXXXXXX 
)
```

Is there a known bug or a backwards incompatible change in API? Had anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the user who authorised a Facebook Page for given Facebook App revokes the token. This is generally possible from Facebook settings page (see [Apps](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) or [Business Integrations](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools)).

You can fix it by re-authorisation of your Page in [developer's portal](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1809136815971857/messenger/settings/) (select your Facebook App, navigate to Settings and scroll to "Token Generation" section). If you don't have the Facebook App than you have to do it in the app of your bot provider.

Notice that there is an ongoing procedure of all Facebook App required to be approved again. But the final deadline is the 1st of August. So this should not be the case.

Comment: The point is, I tried the request with a newly generated token and it didn't help

Comment: Ok, than there might be a problem that the user who did the authorisation was removed from facebook page. See page roles in Facebook page settings.

Comment: The user still is an admin. Moreover, I'm the creator of several pages. I didn't realize the token generated in app dashboard has something to do with the user generating it. Very inconvenient. We'll try creating the token with a different user if it helps, just in case.

Comment: That could be a bug as well. As I said they've done tons of changes regarding users' permissions. You can report bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/support.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug. I didn't change everything and all bots started responding.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the PHP library I was using that sent the data to FB API by encoding with query string. As soon as I changed that with json_encode the problem was fixed. Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: What lib are you using? pimax/fb-messenger-php? 

Anyway, I checked it manually. It failed anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a bug and it was fixed